# Matrix Calculus: Derivative of Vectorized Symmetric Positive Definite Matrix w.r.t. its Vectorized Matrix Logarithm

Tags: matrices, logarithms, matrix-calculus, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

**Setup:**

Let $k\in{}\mathbb{N},$ and let $\mathrm{M}_{k,k}(\mathbb{}{R})$ denote the set of $k\times{}k$ matrices over the field of real numbers.

Let $X\in{}\mathrm{M}_{k,k}(\mathbb{}{R})$ be a symmetric, positive definite matrix.

Then $X$ has $k$ positive eigenvalues $\lambda_{1},\dots{},\lambda_{k}$ with corresponding eigenvectors $v_{1},\dots{},v_{k}$.

The eigendecomposition/spectral decomposition of $X$ is:

$$X = V\Lambda{}V^{-1} = V\Lambda{}V',$$

where $\Lambda{}=\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_{1},\dots{},\lambda_{k})\in{}\mathrm{M}_{k,k}(\mathbb{}{R})$ is the diagonal matrix with the $k$ eigenvalues on the main diagonal and $V=(v_{1},\dots{},v_{k})\in{}\mathrm{M}_{k,k}(\mathbb{}{R})$ is the matrix whose $k$ columns are the orthonormal eigenvectors.

We define the natural matrix logarithm of $X$, denoted $\log{}(X)$, to be
$$\log{}(X)=V\log{}(\Lambda{})V',$$
where $\log{}(\Lambda{})=\mathrm{diag}(\log{}(\lambda_{1}),\dots{},\log{}(\lambda_{k}))\in{}\mathrm{M}_{k,k}(\mathbb{}{R})$.

**Question:**

What, if it can be found, is the analytical form of the $[k(k+1)/2] \times{} [k(k+1)/2]$ Jacobian matrix

$$\frac{\partial{}\mathrm{vec}(X)}{\partial{}\mathrm{vec}(\log{}(X))'}$$

where $\mathrm{vec}(\cdot{})$ is the half-vectorization operator that stacks the lower triangular part of its square argument matrix.

*(Background: This is a recurring problem in multivariate statistics when one adopts a "log-parameterization" of a covariance or precision matrix, which are both, by definition, symmetric and positive (semi-)definite.)*

Comment: I have replaced in you very well presented question all "vech"s by "vec"s.

Comment: @JeanMarie:

It is quite common that $\mathrm{vech}(\cdot{})$ refers to the half-vectorization operator, whereas $\mathrm{vec}(\cdot{})$ refers to the full vectorization operator.

As both $X$ and $\log{}(X)$ are symmetric, I am interested in $\partial{}\mathrm{vech}(X)/\partial{}\mathrm{vech}(\log{}(X))$.

Comment: Maybe to see this better, note that $\partial{}\mathrm{vech}(X)/\partial{}\mathrm{vech}(\log{}(X))'$, is a $[k(k+1)/2]\times{}[k(k+1)/2]$ matrix, whereas $\partial{}\mathrm{vec}(X)/\partial{}\mathrm{vec}(\log{}(X))'$ would be a $k^{2}\times{}k^{2}$ matrix

(But I am quite new to this forum and not fully familiar with the editing/changing questions system yet, so apologies if there are mistakes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $$\eqalign{
  G &= \log(X) \implies X = e^G \cr
}$$
and find the differential of $X$ via the power series of the exponential
$$\eqalign{
dX=de^G &= d\,\Bigg[\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{G^i}{i!}\Bigg] \cr
&= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i!}\,\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}\,G^{j}\,dG\,G^{i-j-1}\cr
}$$
Now apply vectorization
$$\eqalign{
dx &=\Bigg[\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i!}\,\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}G^{i-j-1}\otimes G^{j}\Bigg]\,dg \cr
\frac{\partial x}{\partial g} &= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i!}\,\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}\,\Big[G^{i-j-1}\otimes G^{j}\,\Big] \cr\cr
}$$
To change between vectorization and half-vectorization, multipy by [Duplication and Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplication_and_elimination_matrices) matrices of the appropriate dimensions
$$\eqalign{
L_k\,dx &= L_k\Bigg[\frac{\partial x}{\partial g}\Bigg]D_kL_k\,dg \cr
dx^\prime &= L_k\Bigg[\frac{\partial x}{\partial g}\Bigg]D_k\,dg^\prime \cr
\frac{\partial x^\prime}{\partial g^\prime} &= L_k\Bigg[\frac{\partial x}{\partial g}\Bigg]D_k \cr
\cr\cr
}$$
P.S.

The reason I used $G$ for the log, was because I wanted to use $L$ for the elimination matrix.

In the vectorization of the power series I used the fact that $G$ is symmetric to omit some transpose operations.

### Update

The eigendecomposition can be used to obtain a more compact answer $$\eqalign{
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\R{{\cal R}}
\def\L{\Lambda}
\def\l{\lambda}
 X &= V^T\L\:V \\
 G &= \log(X) \;=\; V^T\log(\L)\:V \\
}$$
Invoking the Daleckii-Krein theorem yields
$$\eqalign{
&V^T\,dG\:V = R\odot\LR{V^T\,dX\:V} \\
\\
&R_{jk} = \begin{cases}
{\Large\frac{\log(\l_j)-\log(\l_k)}{\l_j-\l_k}}
 \qquad{\rm if}\;\l_j\ne \l_k \\
\\
\qquad\quad \l_k^{-1} \qquad\qquad\quad {\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
}$$
where $\odot$ denotes the Hadamard product.

Vectorization (using Kronecker products) yields the desired gradient
$$\eqalign{
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\p{\partial} \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\LR{V\otimes V}^T\vc{dG}
 &= \vc{R}\odot\LR{V\otimes V}^T\vc{dX} \\
 &= \c{\Diag{\vc{R}}}\:\LR{V\otimes V}^T\vc{dX} \\
 &= \c{\R}\:\LR{V\otimes V}^T\vc{dX} \\
\grad{\vc{G}}{\vc{X}}
 &= \LR{V\otimes V}\,\R\:\LR{V\otimes V}^T \\
}$$

Comment: You are an expert in matrix calculations and such, and I don't doubt in many other things as well. I've never encountered half the methods you use to solve problems,thanks for the links on duplication and elimination.